# 404 Error from HttpClient on Windows Azure Website

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, dotnet-httpclient

I am having an issue getting an HttpClient to work from a Windows Azure website.  When running the site from my local machine or a local server it is able to connect to the web services without issue.  However, once I publish it to Azure it returns a 404 error from the SendAsync method.  I would assume a network problem except that if I do a $.getJSON(...) call to the exact same service from the exact same site I get the response back with no issue. I have tried everything I could think of but am currently out of ideas, has anyone experienced anything like this?

Comment: I would first compare the requests generated by HttpClient and the ajax call to see what is different...the url could be different etc.

Comment: thanks Kiran I have validated that the URLs are the same (via remote debugging for the HttpClient and copied and pasted that URL into the ajax call).  works with the ajax call, 404 with httpclient.

Comment: Note that $.getJSON is actually a client call, try going to https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole there you'll have a terminal, use `curl` to make your http request from the server to see whether there is an actual network issue.

Comment: Amit, thanks for the suggestion I did not know about the DebugConsole (relatively new to Azure) and I got the same 404 error using curl.  So it would appear to be a network issue, but unfortunately I am not sure where to go from here.  I will get with my network guy and see if the issue is with the VPN setup.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you overcome this?

Comment: I am also looking into a similar issue, except this is on a VM hosted by my company.